# Use Different CRUD Submit Button in Same View in ASP.NET Core with Entity Framework Core

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, http-post, crud, razor-pages

I manage the read, update and delete process from a database through Entity Framework Core via three different buttons in a Razor page structure on ASP.NET Core.

I'm sending a class to a .cshtml page via the ASP.NET Core controller; this class contains a database list and a database list item. This way I can show the entire database list if one row is under a database list item.

I don't have any problems with the "delete" button from these three different buttons that I placed in this .cshtml because I can delete the selected data from the database by sending a getID via this button.
Similarly, when I use the "delete" and "read" or "delete" and "update" buttons in this .cshtml, I still have no problems.

My problem is that when "read", "update" and "delete" are simultaneous, I cannot determine the different triggering from the buttons separately into the same [HttpPost] View connected to the Controller.

What I want to do is very simple:

If the "read" button is pressed, the item belonging to the "id" value should be shown in a single line in .cshtml according to the entered database "id" value.

If the "update" button is pressed, changes should be made in the single line item in .cshtml according to the entered database "id" value.

If the "delete" button is pressed, the database item of the entered database "id" value must be deleted.

All of these buttons are in a single .cshtml and all return a single "post" value, but there are three different options that I cannot understand on the Controller which button is pressed.

Note: My code left in here is perfectly Update a row in DB and Delete a row in DB but could not be achieved Read a row in DB. When Read method, samely change data and route to UpdateDB. Because, I've succeed Delete a row in DB only returning id value; but Read and Update need different HttpPost structure or so I think

Sample Code Structure:

**Sending C# Class in ASP.NET Core View.cshtml and HomeController.cs**

```
//Here is my sending class. "SendingClass" will be sent to Index.cshtml via HomeController

    public class SendingClass
    {
        public IEnumerable<ProductDB> GetDB { get; set; }
        public int GetID { get; set; }
        public ProductDB OneRow { get; set; }
    }

//Here is my HomeController

        public class HomeController : Controller
        {
            private IProductRepository repository;
            public HomeController(IProductRepository repo)
            {
                repository = repo;
            }

            public IActionResult DataDel(int id)
            {
                repository.DeleteDB(id);
                var send = new SendingClass
                {
                    GetDB = repository.MyDB,
                    GetID = repository.MyDB.First().ID,
                    OneRow = repository.GetByID(repository.MyDB.First().ID)
                };
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            [HttpGet]
            public IActionResult Index()
            {
                var send = new SendingClass
                {
                    GetDB = repository.MyDB,
                    GetID = repository.MyDB.First().ID,
                    OneRow = repository.GetByID(repository.MyDB.First().ID)
                };
                return View(send);
            }

            [HttpPost]
            public IActionResult Index(SendingClass item)
            {
                item.OneRow.ID = item.GetID;
                if (item.OneRow == null)
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    repository.UpdateDB(item.OneRow);
                }
                var send = new SendingClass
                {
                    GetDB = repository.MyDB,
                    GetID = item.GetID,
                    OneRow = repository.GetByID(item.GetID)
                };
                return View(send);
            }
        }

//UpdateDB: My Ef.Core Database Update Method
//DeleteDB: My Ef.Core Database Delete Method
// repository.MyDB: My database which called in Ef.Core
```

**Here is View.cshtml**

```
@model SendingClass
@{

}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body class="align-items-center">
    <form asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Home" method="post">
        <label>Data Row Number</label>
        <p></p>
        <input type="text" asp-for="@Model.GetID" id="@Model.GetID" />
        <p></p>
        <input type="submit" value="READ" />
        <p></p>
        <input type="submit" value="UPDATE" />
        <p></p>
        <input type="submit" asp-action="DataDel" asp-route-id="@Model.GetID" id="@Model.GetID" value="DELETE" />
        <p></p>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Customer Number</th>
                    <th>Price (Old)</th>
                    <th>Price (New)</th>
                    <th>Checkout</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td asp-for="@Model.OneRow.ID">@Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.OneRow.ID)</td>
                    <td asp-for="@Model.OneRow.Name">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.OneRow.Name)</td>
                    <td asp-for="@Model.OneRow.CustomerNo">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.OneRow.CustomerNo)</td>
                    <td asp-for="@Model.OneRow.PriceOld">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.OneRow.PriceOld)</td>
                    <td asp-for="@Model.OneRow.PriceNew">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.OneRow.PriceNew)</td>
                    <td asp-for="@Model.OneRow.Checkout">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.OneRow.Checkout)</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </form>
    <p></p>
    <table border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>NAME</th>
                <th>NO</th>
                <th>Price (Old)</th>
                <th>Price (New)</th>
                <th>Checkout</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model.GetDB)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.ID)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Name)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.CustomerNo)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.PriceOld)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.PriceNew)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Checkout)</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <p></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My problem is that when "read", "update" and "delete" are simultaneous, I cannot determine the different triggering from the buttons separately into the same [HttpPost] View connected to the Controller.

You could use custom `asp-route-{value}` like `asp-route-myMethod` and set it to `READ` or `UPDATE` as a flag, for example

```
<input type="submit" asp-route-myMethod="READ" value="READ" />
<p></p>
<input type="submit" value="UPDATE" />
<p></p>
<input type="submit" asp-action="DataDel" asp-route-id="@Model.GetID" id="@Model.GetID" value="DELETE" />
```

Then on `POST` action, you could get `myMethod` param from querystring to distinguish

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Index(SendingClass item, [FromQuery] string myMethod = null)
    {
        item.OneRow.ID = item.GetID;
        if (myMethod == "READ")
        {
            //For Read
        }
        else
        {
           //For Update               
            repository.UpdateDB(item.OneRow);
        }
        var send = new SendingClass
            {
                GetDB = repository.MyDB,
                GetID = item.GetID,
                OneRow = repository.GetByID(item.GetID)
            };
        ModelState.Clear();
        return View(send);
    }
```